# How to send the next cookies in get request?

Tags: php

I receive 503 error, but if i send it from inspect element its fine.

The code worked for me before, but in the last few hours the specific website added cf_clearance and I need to add it to the request as well

How do i send the both cookies?

```
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'proxy'=>"",
'header'=> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0\r\n" .
           "Cookie: cf_clearance=3de18fcd39d55ce82d9db-1529352303-31536000; PHPSESSID=oahfun4m7vi3edd71\r\n"
));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = "http://website.com";

$data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

echo $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good example in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php).

```
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);
```

Add line breaks and concatenate.  Your example right now should be resulting in a syntax error because you are not [concatenating](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the two strings.

Comment: i updated the code, its still not working. i miss something?

Comment: Are you sending this from the same computer?  Cloudflare may not allow the same cookie from two different IP addresses.

Comment: yes, same IP. if i send the request from inspect element. with same headers (2 cookies and useraget) its works fine